# How do I get multiple values from one input field in php?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a form that has draggable elements that are dropped into a hidden input field.  I have a php script that gets the values and adds them to an array, which is then added to a database.  I then echo the contents of the array and the array length.  At least that's what it's supposed to do.  However, the array_push function is acting more like array_pop in that it's returning the last element added to the array and keeping the count at 1.  How would I go about looping through and finding each input value?  Sorry if the question title is vague.

**HTML**

```
<input type='hidden' name='findCat[]' id='findCat' value='" +cat.toUpperCase()+ "' />
```

**PHP**

```
if($_POST['submit'] == TRUE){
    $findCat = $_POST['findCat'];
    $emerg_array = array($findCat);
    $arrayLength = count($emerg_array);

    for($i = 0; $i < $arrayLength; $i++){
        echo $emerg_array[$i] .'<br>';
    }
    echo $arrayLength;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

Array

1

Regardless of how many elements are in the array.

Comment: `I have a form that has draggable elements that are dropped into a hidden input field.` Then you will need some javascript to concatenate the new "dropped" value with any existing value.  Show your javascript code if you have some please.

Comment: **JS**

`$("#scenario table").append("<tr><td name='cat'><input type='hidden' name='findCat' id='findCat' value='" +cat.toUpperCase()+ "' />" +cat.toUpperCase() +"</td>`

The Javascript portion works fine.  However, what I failed to mention and will add is that I'm using PHP to add the contents of the array to a database.

Comment: This shows that you are adding a NEW input field every time one is dropped, vs "only one input field".  Change name to findCat[] and it should work as Devon showed.

Comment: It should work, but it unfortunately doesn't.  I keep getting an undefined index error in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array with any form element easily by adding `[]` to the name.

```
<input type='hidden' name='array[]' value='1234'>
<input type='hidden' name='array[]' value='5678'>
```

`$_POST['array']` will contain 1234,5678.

Comment: I only have one input field though.  And the value dynamically changes each time the user drops the draggable element.

Comment: @Robert So you re-submit the form each time there is a drag/drop?

Comment: No, what happens is the user drags an element from one side of the page and drops it into a form on the other side of the page.  He/She can do this with multiple elements, but once they're dropped, they're supposed to take on the same name attribute.  For instance if it's something like this:

Left side of page:
Robert
Jon
James

Right side of page:
`<input type="hidden" name="name" />`

The user can drag each name and drop it on the right side of the page and each name will be placed into the input field and take on the name attribute.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think it's kinda like using variable variables, but I'm not sure how to get the loop to iterate through and get each one.

Comment: I understand what you're saying to do by creating the name attribute as an array, and although it should work, it's not.

Comment: @Robert, update your answer with your new code and I'll take a look.  What sometimes helps is printing out the POST to see what is being submitted: `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: @Robert, you suffixed `[]` to the id, not the name.  The array_push is pretty pointless because you are defining `$emerg_array` as an empty array right before it, just use `$_POST['findCat']`.

Comment: I actually made a typo with the edit.  I also did as you said, but I'm still not getting the desired results.  I edited my code again.  Sorry I'm being so difficult with this.

Comment: @Robert, $_POST['findCat'] is already an array.  So what you are doing in the code is adding a nested array so the count of $emerg_array will always be 1, since it contains 1 nested array.  Print out $emerg_array to confirm what I am saying.  If you want to use $emerg_array, set it equal to $_POST['findCat']

Comment: Ah, ok.  thank you very much for your help.  Sorry again I was so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example that works:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    echo "<html><body>
    <form method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='findCat[]' value='1'>
        <input type='hidden' name='findCat[]' value='2'>
        <input type='hidden' name='findCat[]' value='3'>
        <input type='submit' name='sub' value='submit'>
    </form>
    </body></html>";
} else {
    $findCat = $_POST['findCat'];
    var_dump($findCat); // displays array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" } 
}
?>
```

Could it be that your `secure` function is mangling the array?

Comment: I thought that could be the problem so I got rid of it, but that's not the issue.